# Unit Test - Verify Observable is subscribed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, observable

I have got the java code like this

```
 mDataManager.getObservable("hello").subscribe( subscriber );
```

and I want to `verify` the following Observable is being `.subscribe()`

I have tried to mock `getObservable()` and `verify`

```
 Observable<Response> res = mock(Observable.class);
 when(mDataManager.getObservable("hello")).thenReturn(res);
 verify(res).subscribe();
```

But there is an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: onSubscribe function can not be null.
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8167)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8158)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7962)
....
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: omni.neo.hk.omniapiservice.v4.model.external.UserLoginBean.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:109)
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:187)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:82)
... 48 more
```

I think it is not possible `mock` an Observable here, but without an mocked Observable I cannot do`verify(res).subscribe()`

Any suggestion in this case?

Comment: can you post the complete code? I mean a runnable version.

Comment: Why mock an Observable, rather than pushing a value through it and seeing if you get the action you want?

Comment: @JeffBowman If I rewrite the code like this, `Observable<Response> res = Observable.just(new Response());` I cannot do `verify(res).subscribe();` because `res` is not a mocked object

Comment: But you're trying to prove your system works, right? It seems like `verify`ing a call to `subscribe` is much less interesting and useful than watching your class-under-test change state when you update the Observable. So don't worry about verifying, just change the value on a real Observable and see what happens.

Comment: @KoneMan this is your chance to write a nice unit test that doesn't depend on an implementation detail like `subscribe` on the instance of `Observable`. Consider testing against the final result that comes from the subscription to the `Observable` and you will have a nice 'black box' test.

Comment: @JeffBowman what I want to achieve in `verify(res).subscribe();` is to know the observable is actually subscribed. We sometimes miss the `subscribe()` when coding

Comment: I think this question definitely deserves an answer

Answer (score 2):

I found that RxJava provides a class called `TestSubject`

You can create it like this

```
private TestScheduler eventsScheduler = new TestScheduler();
private TestSubject<MyEvent> eventObservable = TestSubject.create(eventsScheduler);
```

This will provide you with the method `hasObservers()` which returns a boolean.

```
@Test
public void testSubscription(){
    myTestClass.init(eventObservable);

    assertTrue(eventObservable.hasObservers());
}
```

Also the TestSubject allows you to perfectly time when events should be sent.

```
eventObservable.onNext(new MyEvent());
eventsScheduler.triggerActions();
```

Comment: TestSubject has been dropped in RxJava2. Its functionality can be achieved via `TestScheduler`, `PublishProcessor/PublishSubject` and `observeOn(testScheduler)`/scheduler parameter: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#testsubject

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `Observable.onSubscribe` method together with `RunTestOnContext` rule? The `TestContext` can provide you with an `Async` object, that terminates the test only once it is completed. I think, that if you combine this with `Observable#doOnSubscribe` you can achieve the desired behavior.

However, using `Async` might be a bit confusing sometimes. In the example below, if the observable is never subscribed onto, the `doOnSubscribe` function would never get evaluated and your test would not terminate.

Example:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class SubscriptionTest {

  @Rule
  public RunTestOnContext vertxRule = new RunTestOnContext();

  @Test
  public void observableMustBeSubscribed(final TestContext context) {
    final Async async = context.async();
    final Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("hello").doOnSubscribe(async::complete);
    final Manager mock = mock(Manager.class);
    when(mock.getObservable()).thenReturn(observable);

    mock.getObservable().subscribe();
  }

  interface Manager {
    Observable<String> getObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for helping out with an answer, but if would be even more helpful if you added some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I am answering the asked question, but I *think* so...

Unit tests can be created that check whether a subscription has been made to an observable.  Note that in RxJava 1.x, this was supported with TestSubject, but that functionality can be facilitated by Subject implementations.  TestSubject was [dropped for RxJava 2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0).

Rather than attempting to mock the observable as the original poster is trying to do, use a PublishSubject, run the business logic, then use the publish subject to see if the Observable is being observed.  Below is some test code that validates this testing is possible.  The tests pass when I run them.

See code comments for description of the code.  Personally, this test seems redundant to other tests that would verify how the controller handles data.  Those other tests would fail if the controller never subscribed to and received data from the data service.  On the other hand, testing unsubscribe helps avoid memory leaks, which is probably high value.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * Tests whether it is possible to test whether a controller properly unsubscribes from an Observable.
 */
public class SubscribeUnsubscribeTests {

    /**
     * A service that returns a stream of strings.
     */
    interface StringService {
        Observable<String> getStrings();
    }

    /**
     * A controller that requests strings from the {@link StringService} and logs them
     * to system out as they are received.
     */
    class StringLoggingController {

        private StringService stringService;

        private Disposable stringSubscriptionDisposable;

        public StringLoggingController(StringService stringService) {
            this.stringService = stringService;
        }

        /**
         * Causese the controller to begin strings request and logging.
         */
        public void start() {
            stringSubscriptionDisposable = stringService.getStrings()
                    .subscribe(string -> System.out.print(string));
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (stringSubscriptionDisposable != null) {
                if (!stringSubscriptionDisposable.isDisposed()) {
                    stringSubscriptionDisposable.dispose();
                    stringSubscriptionDisposable = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link StringService} that can report whether {@link StringService#getStrings()}
     * has observers.
     */
    class ReportIsSubscribedStringService implements StringService {

        private PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        public Observable<String> getStrings() {
            return publishSubject;
        }

        /**
         * @return true if the {@link #getStrings()} observable has observers.
         */
        public boolean stringsAreBeingObserved() {
            return publishSubject.hasObservers();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the {@link StringLoggingController} is subscribing to the service.
     */
    @Test
    public void stringsLoggingControllerSubscribesToStringService() {
        ReportIsSubscribedStringService service = new ReportIsSubscribedStringService();
        StringLoggingController controller = new StringLoggingController(service);

        controller.start();
        assertTrue(service.stringsAreBeingObserved());
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the {@link StringLoggingController} is unsubscribing from the service.
     */
    @Test
    public void stringsLoggingControllerUnsubscribesFromStringService() {
        ReportIsSubscribedStringService service = new ReportIsSubscribedStringService();
        StringLoggingController controller = new StringLoggingController(service);

        controller.start();
        controller.stop();

        assertFalse(service.stringsAreBeingObserved());
    }
}
```

-- edit --
I previously wrote that I wasn't able to test for unsubscribe.  I did figure out how to test that.  It turns out my test was failing because the tested code wasn't properly unsubscribing (hah - testing works, go figure).  I've updated the code above to illustrate testing both subscribe and unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours today and realize it was a silly mistake.
Please check your @PrepareForTest if you are using PowerMockito.

```
@PrepareForTest({Observable.class})
```

also don't forget to mock it. I did it on @before :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Observable.class);
```

I hope it can help. Thank you