# RxJava2 : How to test an observable is subscribed with TestObserver

Tags: rx-java2

Using `Observable.test()` to get a test observer seems to be a bit messed up ... as `.test()` creates a subscription to the observable giving the following erroneous tests.

```
// fixme: test passes but TestObservable is always true even if disp= ..  is commented out
@Test
fun `with subscription`() { 
    val observable = Observable.never<String>()
    val test = observable.test()
    val disp = observable.subscribe()
    test.assertSubscribed()
}

// fixme: this test should not pass
@Test
fun `without subscription`() {
    val observable = Observable.never<String>()
    val test = observable.test()
    test.assertSubscribed()
}
```

It seems the only way to test an observable is subscribed - is to use a `PublishSubject` as below, which both pass as expected (taken from this for rx-java1 (no TestSubject in rx2) [Unit Test - Verify Observable is subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500312/unit-test-verify-observable-is-subscribed))

```
@Test
fun `with subscription subject`() {
    val observable = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    val disp = observable.subscribe()
    assertTrue(observable.hasObservers())
}

@Test
fun `without subscription subject`() {
    val observable = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    assertFalse(observable.hasObservers())
}
```

Is there a way to make a proper test for subscription using `Observable.test()`?

Comment: Makes no sense. Cold observables will serve any number of subscribers as they get individual subscriptions going on and won't know about each other. So what remains is checking with a hot observable like `PublishSubject` or side-effecting the flow with `doOnSubscribe` and count the number of subscriptions passing through.

Comment: that's interesting - it seems like side effecting the obsevable is a bit hacky as it adds additional behaviour to what would not be used in production. Would you say one is better than the other? I know know side-effecting is done all the time so i guess not.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test. Testing standard sources is a waste of time as we already test those for you. Do you have something more specific to your case you want to check for proper subscriptions? Isn't it enough to detect items/termination with `TestObserver` proof enough that there must have been a subscription?

Comment: I just wanted to test that the observable is subscribed in sut. It seemed to me that using side effects was a bit hacky as it adds additional behaviour to what would not be there in production - whereas using a Subject doesnt require side effects. if the method under tests doesnt dispose the disposable then you need to check if that observable is currently subscribed. I was just interested in your opinion ...

Comment: so the use case is a simple android presenter where you would have a compositeDisposable holding subscriptions until the view is destroyed